# Adding a picture to Word Document using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I know it is already possible to add a picture to Word document using the

```
XWPFRun: addPicture(java.io.InputStream pictureData, int pictureType, java.lang.String filename, int width, int height) throws InvalidFormatException, java.io.IOException
```

method. However, I don't want my Picture to be resized. The resizing is not scaling the new images: it is always stretching them, making them useless.

**Is there a way to insert image with original size, or scale them proportionally???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used Apache POI for quite some time and I don't think it's possible to add picture to a WORD doc without specifying height and width.

I always use following code to retrieve the size of a picture and scale them accordingly if needed.

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
int width          = bi.getWidth();
int height         = bi.getHeight();
```

Comment: I see... Sadly that can't work for me since I'm using it on Google App Engine and awt classes are not supported there.

So manual scaling combined with the passing the actual image width/height after it, is the only solution after all.

Comment: There are non-AWT based image metadata libraries for Java - what happens if you try one of those?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache POI ImageUtils as following:

```
Dimension dimension = ImageUtils.getImageDimension(imageInputStream, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
double width = dimension.getWidth();
double height = dimension.getHeight();
```